# ReadKey() doesn't track keystrokes in other windows or instances

Tags: powershell, readkey

I wrote a simple script to track keys being pressed and released as shown below:

```
$j = 0
while($j -lt 10000){
    $PressedKey = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown,IncludeKeyUp")
    $PressedKey
    continue
}
```

When I run it and start pressing keys, it works. However when I switch to a different Instance or Window and start pressing keys, it stops giving an output. I assume this is because it stops tracking the keystrokes, can't produce an output, or both. Does anyone know any good alternatives to ReadKey() to how to make it track keystrokes on other Windows and/or Instances

I believe this is PowerShell 7

thx.

Answer (score 1):

The object `$Host` refers to the current PowerShell console host. Therefore, connecting to the `ReadKey()` method will only return the current PowerShell host keystrokes, and that is the point of the `ReadKey()` method, return the current host's keystrokes so that other functions (e.g. `PSReadline`) can act on them.

If you want to globally respond to keystrokes across applications, I personally recommend [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). It is fairly easy to create a script that will detect a key combination and perform an action. It is fast and easy to use and I have dozens of key combinations that I have scripted and use every day.

It is possible to create PowerShell scripts that globally hook into keyboard keystrokes and respond to events, but this is beyond the scope of a SO post.

Comment: Well done. Worth pointing out that attempting to track _all_ keystrokes _system-wide_, as the question seems to ask for, is usually associated with nefarious intent.